# Как отменить свойства псевдокласса :active для элемента dropdown?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, bootstrap, bootstrap4

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title></title>
  <style>
    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
      display: block;
      margin-top: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-expand-sm">
    <a href="" class="navbar-brand">MySite</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
           <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
       </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
      <ul class="navbar-nav nav-items ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="" class="nav-link">Главная</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a href="" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">О нас</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
            <a href="" class="dropdown-item">Blog</a>
            <a href="" class="dropdown-item">YT</a>
            <a href="" class="dropdown-item">VK</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>


  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

У меня есть .dropdown элемент, для которого по-умолчанию задано поведение при нажатии (:active). Я сделал так, чтобы список в том числе выпадал при наведении на этот элемент.
**Вопрос:** А как сделать так, чтобы элемент выпадал только при наведении на него, т.е. чтобы псевдокласс :active не срабатывал?

Comment: @MaximLensky теперь не закроют?)

Comment: теперь всё в ёлочку

Comment: таки имею вопрос: а зачем? раз он выпадает при наведении, то он останется выпавшим независимо от того, будет элемент :active или нет.

Comment: @Инквизитор я не хочу чтобы он оставался выпавшим когда пользователь отводит курсор мыши. На многих сайтах списки выпадают только при наведении мыши - я хочу сделать также

Comment: так он и уйдет, если мышь отвести, это подразумевалось. Выкиньте жквери и обработчик нажатия, и всё.

Comment: @Инквизитор убрал .dropdown-toggle и data-toggle="dropdown" - всё заработало. Спасибо

Comment: Можете написать ответ, я помечу как решение

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выкиньте жквери и обработчик нажатия, и всё.